# I am unable to plot 3D graph of integral function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, simplifying-expressions, interpolation

I am not able to solve this integral

```
Integrate[
 1/(0.0007155* (67 + 58* Sin[1.5708 - 7.45356* \[Zeta]])^(3/2))*
  Exp[(125*y^2)/(67 + 58* Sin[1.5708 - 7.45356 *\[Zeta]])], \[Zeta]]
```

I also tried directly to plot this but didn't get any plot

```
Plot3D[1397.54* 
     0.004074464993818227` \[Integral]E^(-((125.` y^2)/(
     67.` + 58.` Sin[
        1.5707963267948968` - 7.4535599249993` \[Zeta]])))/(67.` + 
      58.` Sin[1.5707963267948968` - 7.4535599249993` \[Zeta]])^(
    3/2) \[DifferentialD]\[Zeta], {\[Zeta], 0, 3}, {y, 0, 1.5}]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The code you have included so far does not evaluate. You can copy code directly from the input cell and paste in the edit windows. There is the `{  }` icon there to format code.

Comment: thanks i have edit the question

Comment: Are you sure that a closed form for this integral exists?

Comment: You can replace all these numbers by symbols and see more clearly that Mathematica can't integrate this. Screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLFk1.png)  so before worrying about the Plot part, you need to worry about how to do the integration.

Comment: May be you could look at numerical integration if you have values for the range and `y`.

Comment: there is some problem with this function  Sin[1.5707963267948968` - 7.4535599249993` \[Zeta]]

Comment: i think it is not valid to write Sin[x] instead of Sinx

Comment: @HimaniJuneja Why do you think `Sin[x]` is not valid? That's normal Mathematica syntax. Where do you see the problem?

Comment: sorry Sin[x] is valid. i don't know why it is not solving this integral